# Async Images Download in a Table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I have a table view and I'd like to download an icon image (100x75) to each row asynchronously. I've followed many tutorials so far but I can't seem to figure it out. How should I do it?

Does anyone recommend just doing it using the standard NSURLConnection API or should I use one of those classes/libraries that are available online to do so? If so, what do you recommend?

Of course, I need it to be fast, efficient and does not leak. I also don't want the downloading to affect the scrolling.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you using ASIHTTPRequest. Its simple and pretty fast. 
Here is a link to the documentation - [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

**EDIT**

You need to download images for visible cells only.
Heres a sample:

```
- (void)loadContentForVisibleCells
{
    NSArray *cells = [self.tableView visibleCells];
    [cells retain];
    for (int i = 0; i < [cells count]; i++) 
    { 
        ...
        // Request should be here
        ...
    }
    [cells release];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
{
    if (!decelerate) 
    {
        [self loadContentForVisibleCells]; 
    }
}
```

Anyway u'll need to code a lot to make things work good and fast.

Comment: Yeah I am using ASIHTTPRequest for other things in my app - but how would you use it for images in a table view efficiently? Not sure about that - Tried reading http://kosmaczewski.net/2009/03/08/asynchronous-loading-of-images-in-a-uitableview/ but his app does not work when I run it, and it uses Core Animation which gets too complicated for what I need. Decoding his code would take me more time.

Answer (score 1):

Two options I can think of:

(1) Use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use).

(2) A custom implementation that spawns a thread in which you load the image using a combination of `NSURL`/`NSData`. Once the image is loaded, send it to a method on the main UI thread using `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:`.

```
NSThread *t = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadImage:) object:nil];
[t start];
[t release];

-(void) updateImage:(id) obj {
  // do whatever you need to do
}

-(void) loadImage:(id) obj {

  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"imageurl"];
  NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
  [imageData release];

  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateImage:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];  
  [pool release];

}
```

Comment: I think that threading for images in a table is not a good idea. As for ASIHTTPRequest, I am using it for other things in my app - but how would you use it for images in a table view efficiently? Not sure about that - Tried reading kosmaczewski.net/2009/03/08/… but his app does not work when I run it, and it uses Core Animation which gets too complicated for what I need. Decoding his code would take me more time.

Comment: @Nayefc - what are your concerns? I haven't used ASIHTTPRequest, or looked at its source, but I would be surprised if it's not kicking off a background thread of some kind to load resources asynchronously.

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to use ASIHTTPRequest (or which methods precisely) to achieve what I want in a table view. I know how to use it without a table, but a table (with scrolling) makes things trickier.